# creating an Info-box like control in .NET 2

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

i want to create an info box in .net 2 (attached is an image with an example)
[image]
I wanted to use a panel, but I cannot change the color of its border.

is it possible to change this property? if so, how?

Thanks,
Shuky[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the color of the border directly, but, you draw your own in any color and style you wish. See [this article](http://vicky4147.wordpress.com/2007/03/04/how-to-draw-a-custom-border-around-a-form-or-control/).

Example of the code from the article. (That's all you'll need.)

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)     {
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, this.panel1.ClientRectangle, 
    Color.DarkBlue, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
}

private void panel1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Invalidate();
}
```